# Android daily job at 12 AM

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I have an application working on awake screen all time without exit from application or sleep.

How to make **daily job** for a long time at 12 AM to change display values in layout and execute some methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager to do such tasks. Schedule a task with appropriate delay time in AlarmManager and start a service from AlarmManager. In that service, you can define whatever methods or code you want to execute at that specified time.

Comment: what about repeat the job every day

Comment: Reschedule the job recursively inside the service for next interval. Make sure to call objService,stopService(context) after rescheduling as not doing so may result in memory leakage.